# Nexus file doesn't download

Tags: nexus-7

Tonight I tried to install to my Nexus 7. I am following [this wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation).

I received no errors up until the graphical failed with a checksum error. I read another post that asked me to look in my downloads/Nexus folder. The only file I get is ubuntu-nexus7-USAGE-NOTICE-en.txt. I have tried deleting the folder a couple of times, but that is the only file I get. There was a suggestion to download the files directly, but I can't find the download link.

I appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the one [Ubuntu 13.04 image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.04/release/ubuntu-13.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+nexus7.img.gz).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the desktop install of Ubuntu onto Nexus 7 is now defunct/abandoned/deprecated, and now the 'official' way to install Ubuntu on the Nexus 7 is to install Ubuntu Touch preview.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

I have installed both the old desktop 13.04 image of Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 (2012) many months ago (it was useless, you are not missing out), and today I managed to successfully the Ubuntu Touch dev preview on the same tablet (after being unavailable for 'grouper' (wifi only) Nexus 7's it is now once again able to be installed).

I did it following the instructions on the wiki, but with two caveats: the "generic" command

`phablet-flash (cdimage-touch|cdimage-legacy|ubuntu-system|community) -b`

doesn't seem to be valid - so I just used this instead:

`phablet-flash cdimage-touch -b`

Also adb tried to 'push' the autoload.zip it failed so I had to sideload it manually.

If you need any other help post more info.